# How to increase column limit of a table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

SQLite: How can we configure the maximum number of columns allowed in a table?

Comment: If you need more than 2000 columns this almost always indicates a bad database model (i.e. not normalized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per SQLite documentation [Limits In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

> "Limits" in the context of sizes or quantities that can not be exceeded. We are concerned with things like the maximum number of bytes in a BLOB or the maximum number of columns in a table.
>   [...]
>
> **Maximum Number Of Columns**
>
> The `SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN` compile-time parameter is used to set an upper bound on:
>
> - The number of columns in a table
> - The number of columns in an index
> - The number of columns in a view
> - The number of terms in the SET clause of an UPDATE statement
> - The number of columns in the result set of a SELECT statement
> - The number of terms in a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause
> - The number of values in an INSERT statement
>
> The default setting for **`SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN`** is **`2000`**. You can change it at compile time to values as large as **`32767`**. On the other hand, many experienced database designers will argue that a well-normalized database will never need more than 100 columns in a table.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to obtain the Source Code for SQLLite, change the value of SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN, recompile the code and distrbute the resulting executable.

However, more than 2000 columns in a single table sounds *wrong* to me. 
Do you have lots of repeated fields in each row?  That's poor Relational design.

If necessary, create a second table with the same primary key as the first and add your additional fields into that.  You would have to issue two select statements to retrieve the values, though, because SQLITE_MAX_COLUMNS also applies to select statements, so you can't just join the two tables together.

Answer (score 2):

As specified in [Limits In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

> The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is `2000`. You can change it at compile time to values as large as `32767`. On the other hand, many experienced database designers will argue that a well-normalized database will never need more than `100` columns in a table.

You will have to compile SQLite with the corresponding [compile-time option](https://sqlite.org/compile.html) `SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN` as described in [How To Compile SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html)

I downloaded and unpacked the snapshot version from the [Download page](https://sqlite.org/download.html),

- First ran `./configure` and
- Waited till the `Makefile` had been created
- Opened the `Makefile` and added `-DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=32767` to the end of the line starting `DEFS =` and saved the file.
- Finally, ran `make` to compile the binary (this is for Linux/macOS/*nix, though)

---

For an edge case I also had to increase the following options (none of this is recommended)

`-DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=32767 -DSQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH=1073741824 -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=1273741824 -DSQLITE_MAX_FUNCTION_ARG=127 -DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=65534`